# Python: Instance class mutation

Tags: python

I have two classes:

```
class Egg:
    def __init__(self):
        self._color = 'White'

class Larvae(Egg):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._color = 'Transparente'
```

To illustrate ...

[image: Ant cycle illustration]

So, in my code I have an Egg instance. When it's time I would like transform them into Larvae instances. I can create a Larvae instance and hand copy informations about a "previous" Egg instance. What does Python offer for something like that? For "mute" an instance in instance of subclass of its class?

**Edit: As commented below, OOP in this question is not good way to do the wanted behavior. So, keep this in mind when reading answer**

Comment: Could you use a state-based approach?

Comment: This is some strange OOP. Larvae is not an egg, etc. It's not supposed to have the interfaces of an egg.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Pertinent comment. Egg and Larvae share things (like "digest", "grow_old", etc ...) What is your advise to represent that in OOP ?

Comment: Not everything fits nicely with the concept of inheritance. Python, especially, has this "duck typing" feature which means if two classes walk and talk like ducks, it doesn't matter if they are descendants of a `Duck` class or not. The fact that, e.g., `Egg` and `Larvae` share things in common doesn't *necessarily* mean that `Larvae` should descend from `Egg` in a class hierarchy.

Comment: @bux I've added an snippet of a better OO structure.

Comment: Do they have behaviour or just attributes?

Comment: @PeterWood Twice. For exemple, an egg and an larva share ``_id``, ``_age`` ... attributes and ``grow_up``, ``digest`` ... behaviours.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a state-based approach?

```
class Ant:
    def __init__(self, state='egg'):
        self.state = state

    @property
    def color(self):
        return {
            'egg': 'Transparent',
            'larvae': 'White,'
        }[self.state]

    def hatch(self):
        if self.state == 'egg':
            self.state = 'larvae'
        else:
            raise Exception('Cannot hatch if not an egg!')
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is possible, but not a great idea**.

It is possible to change the type of an object after constructing it, but, well, it's just not robust.  When you change the type of an object, its `__init__()` does not run.  Any attributes left over from the old type are still there, and if they clash with attributes belonging to the new type, you probably have a nasty mess to deal with.  If you're really sure this is the right approach, you can do it by assigning to the `__class__` attribute (e.g. `spam.__class__ = SomeClass`).  I strongly advise against this, however.

Instead, I would recommend factoring out the data you want to preserve into a "state" attribute, which you then transfer from one type to another.  For example:

```
class Egg(object):
    def __init__(self, state):
        # Other egg-related stuff here...
        self.state = state
    def grow_up(self):
        return Larva(self.state)

class Larva(object):
    def __init__(self, state):
        # Other larva-related stuff here...
        self.state = state
    def grow_up(self):
        return Pupa(self.state)

class Pupa(object):
    # and so on...

spam = Egg([1, 2, 3])
spam = spam.grow_up()
print(spam.state)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: For clarity: My `state` attribute is very different from @NickT's `state` attribute; either approach can work depending on your needs.

Comment: Or even have the initializer for `Larva` take an `Egg` instance, and access the state of the `Egg` through its methods. But I agree that this is the right approach. One could even use abstract base classes to define an interface that the three classes have in common.

Comment: @jme: I would recommend taking an `Egg` parameter if we're certain the OP's lifecycle diagram is the *only* way an object can be constructed.  If it's possible to jump into the middle and construct a larva "from scratch," it may be preferable to encapsulate the state in a separate object as I've shown, or perhaps even a full-blown class (or at least a namedtuple).  One could also split the state into multiple parameters, if that works better.

Comment: Good point re: creating a `Larva` from scratch. Perhaps a class method (`Larva.from_egg`) would make sense as an alternate constructor.

Comment: If this is a "not a good idea", why did you show the OP how to shoot himself or another in the foot?

Comment: @msw: I don't believe in hiding information.  OP asked how to change the type of an object, and I answered the question.  If they shoot themselves in the foot, that's entirely their own fault with all the warnings I put up.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has little to do with your request, but I find that it's worth to show that your OOP is a little bit counterintuitive. The whole point of OOP is that you create an intuitive inheritance hierarchy. There is little point in OO if your low level classes are supposed to be aware of higher level ones. In your use-case the `Egg` must be aware of the `Larvae` in order to transform, but that makes little sense. A parent class should not reference its child-classes.

```
class BaseInsect(object):
    """
    Some stuff that all insects share at any stage
    """
    def __init__(self, colour, *args, **kwargs):
        self.colour = colour
        ...


class ImmatureAnt(BaseInsect):
    ...


class Egg(ImmatureAnt):
    """
    Some egg-specific stuff
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Egg, self).__init__("white")
        ...


class Larvae(ImmatureAnt):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Larvae, self).__init__("transparent")
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def from_egg(egg, *args, **kwargs):
        # make a larvae out of an egg
    ...


class BaseAdultAnt(BaseInsect):
    """
    Some stuff all adult ants have
    """
    ...

class WorkerAnt(BaseAdultAnt):
    ...


class BaseReproducingAnt(BaseAdultAnt):
    ...


class Male(BaseReproducingAnt):
    ...


class Queen(BaseReproducingAnt):
    ...
```

Back to your question.

You've already been told that you can pass an `Egg` instance to the `Larvae` constructor. That will be a beautiful way. To make this answer a little bit less off-topic I'm giving an alternative solution. You might want to use several functions.

```
def egg_to_larvae(egg, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    :param egg: an Egg instance
    :type egg: Egg
    """
    # do some stuff to get all the info needed to create a larvae...

    return larvae   

def larvae_to_pupae(larvae, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return pupae
```

You get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Just use a common base class instead of trying to inherit `Larvae` from an `Egg`:

```
class AntBase:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color = color

class Egg(AntBase):
    def __init__(self, color='White'):
        super().__init__(color)

class Larvae(AntBase):
    def __init__(self, color='Transparente'):
        super().__init__(color)
```

While `Egg` and `Larvae` are similar (both related to ants), `Larvae` is not an `Egg`, nor is an `Egg` a `Larvae`.
They are both "ant-things" though, thus we create a common `AntBase` class for all your ant things.

To convert an `Egg` into a `Larvae`, you can have a converter `classmethod`:

```
class AntBase:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color = color

    @classmethod
    def transform_from(cls, instance):
        return cls(instance._color)
```

And now you can do:

```
egg0 = Egg()
larvae0 = Larvae.transform_from(egg0)
```

You can even have custom behaviour for each class:

```
class Larvae(AntBase):
    @classmethod
    def transform_from(cls, instance):
        if isinstance(instance, AntMale):
            raise ValueError("You can't have Larvae from AntMale")
        return super().transform_from(instance)
```